# Getting powershell to email message queue size before purging the queue

Tags: powershell, msmq

Is there away of getting powershell to email the number of messages in a queue prior to purging the queue ?

I'm able to purge the queue and get it to count the messages, but an email would possibly help identify issues. if the queue was suddenly start ramping up.

I suppose what i need to do is have a script that will count the messages and then if it is above a predefined limit it will send an email with the message count then run the purge on the queue

Answer (score 0):

This is some Powershell code that I use to send emails from Powershell Scripts

```
$smtpServer = ""
$smtpFrom = ""
$smtpTo = ""
$messageSubject = "Email Message";
$messageBody =  "Body of Email"

$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$mail = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$mail.from = $smtpFrom
$mail.to.add($smtpTo)
$mail.subject = $messageSubject
$mail.body = $messageBody
$mail.IsBodyHtml = $true
$smtp.Send($mail)
```